# Cufon replace on className

Tags: javascript, cufon

Trying to run a script on the page load, where if a `className` is detected it does a `Cufon.replace`, effectively overriding any previous Cufon styles.

(very)rough example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = "highvisTheme"){
        Cufon.replace('a.convert-me', { color: '#000' });
    }
}
</script>
```

Go gentle on me. Thanks

Comment: Paul, you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the green tick below the score. This way the question will not appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing an assignment when you should be doing:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className == "highvisTheme") {
```

It's pretty common :), the code looks ok otherwise.